# SQL Server trigger with CTE to update another field after insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I created a trigger to update a column after an insert. The problem that I am running into is that the `IsNowComplete` CTE does not appear to handle multiple "pick lists" with multiple items. How would I account for this scenario? The code that I have for my trigger:

```
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    WITH WasComplete AS 
    (
        SELECT  
            pl.IsComplete, pl.Id
        FROM    
            dbo.PickList pl
        JOIN    
            inserted i ON pl.Id = i.PickListId
    ), IsNowComplete AS 
    (
       SELECT   
           i.PickListId, 
           IsNowComplete = CASE 
                              WHEN COUNT(1) > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1
                           END
       FROM 
           dbo.PickListContent plc
       JOIN 
           inserted i ON plc.PickListId = i.PickListId 
       WHERE    
           plc.PickListId = i.PickListId
           AND plc.QuantityPicked != plc.QuantityNeeded
       GROUP BY
           i.PickListId
    )
    UPDATE pl
    SET IsComplete = CASE 
                         WHEN ws.IsComplete = 0 AND inc.IsNowComplete = 1 
                           THEN 1
                         WHEN ws.IsComplete = 1 AND inc.IsNowComplete = 0 
                           THEN 0
                         ELSE 
                           ws.IsComplete 
                     END
    FROM dbo.PickList pl
    JOIN WasComplete ws ON pl.Id = ws.Id
    JOIN IsNowComplete inc ON ws.Id = inc.PickListId
END
```

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Well I see that you're doing a COUNT(1) without a GROUP BY, which is probably a mistake, but since I don't know your data, current results or desired results, I have no idea what it should be instead.

Comment: I noticed I did not have a GROUP BY after posting.  I edited my statement above.  Thanks.  Still looking to figure out how to account for multiple pick lists that could contain multiple items from inserted.

Comment: @AudiDriver Your WasComplete query takes care of multiple records in inserted by treating it as a table and includes all picklists included in the insert/update. Here I would do a groupby on pl.IsComplete, pl.Id in case inserted contains multiple records of the same PickListId. Your IsComplete query seems to be only half good as it is treating inserted as a table (correctly) and there is a group by to return unique picklists that were affected in this insert/update, but any picklists not having a record in picklistcontent will not be included and will be skipped from your update statement.

Comment: @Adish Thanks for the suggestion. Adding the GROUP BY to the WasComplete CTE along with the IsNowComplete CTE seemed to have solved my issue.  If a record does not exist in picklistcontent, I do not want to perform the update.

Answer (score 0):

Please amend the WHERE clause of isNowComplete as

> AND  plc.QuantityPicked not exists(select plc1.QuantityNeeded from dbo.PickListContent plc1)

You could also use NOT IN, provided there are no null values.

Hope this helps.